# Secure login api with remember me in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, cookies

I am implementing this right now in the following steps -

1. User login with email and password, that send to php backend by JS via ajax request
2. PHP validate it with database, if find true, a hashed token created and that cookie is set while also the session is being set to keep user logged in
3. When user come to the app after a time, session will be expired because it has a very less active duration. So, php check user token cookie which were set while logging in and validate it with database, if find true then user get logged in and no need to re enter email or password

The problem is when user get the cookie value by inspecting tools of the browser it will set that same value in different one and bypass the login to get the access. Is there any better way to do ?

I tried tracking IP but that is not reliable, it will be dynamic.

Comment: You mean site opened in incognito and cookie copied to this incognito tab and voila, the user got logged in?

Comment: "remember me" is not the same as "stay logged in"

Comment: @honkder okay I want stay logged in feature

Comment: @nice_dev yes it is happening the same way

Comment: @ShivamShukla Cookies are meant to work that way in HTTP. It is not a bug. Cookie stealing through social engineering is inevitable. However, cookies should be made secure by making them immune from XSS or CSRF attacks. In your laptop, you were able to access only your account's logged in cookies which is fine.

Comment: @nice_dev but the same thing can be done by any other person and they will logged in same account in their system which is a problem

Comment: @ShivamShukla They are just copying the cookies of their own account to which they had logged in, which is NOT a problem. That's how sessions/cookies work. You can put additional constraints via IP if you wish. The question you have to answer is can they steal other users' cookies by sitting on their machine? If the answer is no, you are safe provided you have `httponly` and `secure` flags set to true for your cookies.

Comment: Rule number one of web development: the user is in control of their own client. If I want to log in using Chrome, then copy the cookie to Firefox and carry on ... that's not a security issue, the cookie is still doing it's job of authenticating me as a particular user of your site. Do you have a specific scenario that you think it's important to prevent?

Comment: I want to prevent access with that cookie if the browser changed or device is changed, so that other person can’t access their account anytime by just having that cookie. @IMSoP

Comment: @ShivamShukla The "just" in that sentence is doing a lot of work. *How* would another person get a copy of that cookie? If they got it from the legitimate user's browser, they *already have access to your site*, by using that browser. When thinking about security, you need to have a particular attack scenario in mind, else you end up with complexity for no gain. For instance, ignoring the extra long life cookie, is your session implementation safe against "session fixation", where an attacker tricks a user into using a session ID of their choice, then waits for them to log in?

Comment: @IMSoP after reading this comment, that the type of cookie stealing I am concern of, is actually a not to worry thing